# Read compressed zraw data from file in std::vector with boost zlib

Tags: c++, boost, zlib

I am trying to read a compressed (3d voxelized image) file using boost and zlib but with no success so far.

My goal is to decompress the data and store them in a std::vector. Are there any more specific examples from this task rather than the examples of boost documentation?

Here is a sample of what I try to do:

```
std::vector<DATATYPE> data;

{
  ifstream file_in("image.zraw", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
  filtering_istream in;
  in.push(zlib_decompressor());
  in.push(file_in);

  //copy somehow memory from in the vector data... DATATYPE is the type of data to be stored in the vector...
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Konstantinos

Comment: Do you have no sample? No code? Because there's nothing we can for you this way. The very best is to point you at those boost samples. Or see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bboost%5D+filtering_stream

Comment: Sorry for that! I edited my question

Comment: What is datatype. How can we ever know how to read something if we don't know 1. The input data 2. What datatype to read

Comment: DATATYPE serves as an arbitrary data type. I want the vector to be templated, it can be anything from the standard types (int, float, etc.)

Comment: So, what is the input? Does .zraw imply a format? Is it supposed to be text serialization? Binary? Must it be platform independent? "from the standard types", does that include `std::string`? `std::complex<>`? `std::tuple<>`? Apparently it does at least include `std::vector<>`. You will have to specify at least parts of the problem, OR give samples of the expected data/behaviour. Otherwise it's like asking "write the program that does input and output, it could be any input or output".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving my problem I post the answer that may be helpful for others

```
 previous stuff.....

// Clear the data storing vector of the image.
this->data_.clear();

// Reserve enough space for the data vector according to image's size.
this->data_.reserve(this->num_voxels_);

// Here happens the decompression.
{
std::ifstream file_in("../data/image.zraw", std::ios::in | std::ios_base::binary);
boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;

in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
in.push(file_in);

// Write the data from the filtering istream to the data_ vector.
char *dptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(this->data_.data());

// DATATYPE is the templated storage type of the vector.
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(DATATYPE)*this->num_voxels_;i++)
    in.read(&dptr[i],1);
}

next stuff.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot specify, I'll just run with an assumption:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c4b3010512f18a8)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>

namespace bio = boost::iostreams;

template <typename T>
void write_data(std::string const& fname, std::vector<T> const& data) {
    std::ofstream ofs(fname, std::ios_base::binary);
    bio::filtering_ostream out;

    out.push(bio::zlib_compressor());
    out.push(ofs);

    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(out);
    oa << data;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> read_data(std::string const& fname) {
    std::vector<T> result;

    std::ifstream file_in(fname, std::ios_base::binary);
    bio::filtering_istream in;

    in.push(bio::zlib_decompressor());
    in.push(file_in);

    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(in);
    ia >> result;

    return result;
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    write_data("floats.zraw", std::vector<float> { 1,2,3 });
    write_data("ints.zraw",   std::vector<int>   { 4,5,6 });

    auto floats = read_data<float>("floats.zraw");
    auto ints   = read_data<int>("ints.zraw");

    std::copy(floats.begin(), floats.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout << '\n', " "));
    std::copy(ints  .begin(), ints  .end(), std::ostream_iterator<int  >(std::cout << '\n', " "));
}
```

Prints

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

It uses Boost Serialization and Boost Iostreams to achieve binary (de)serialization into a compressed file. The format is versatile, not limited to POD data types and NOT platform/library version independent.

Comment: Hi sehe, sorry for not replying to your question. Your code works fine but I get a bad allocatio exception with my data. My data is a compressed 3d metaimage (.mhd). The .mhd is a header accompanying a .raw binary file which contain the binary data of the image. In the case that the image is compressed (with zlib) the binary is .zraw and the compressed data size is given in the header along with the default header info (image dimensions, datatype, spacing, etc..) I hope it helps you understand the application i target.

Comment: Gosh. Why even try "my code" with that. You completely altered the question. By now you seem to specify a full blown raw image format support library. Is there something against using a library for that? SO is not a "magic genie" service where you can just wish for solutions to your programming tasks. It'll have to be realistic and you must do the work

Comment: Obviously Im on the task! Thank you for your tips

Comment: It wasn't that obvious from the lack of crucial information in the question. Good luck!